# Oracle - complex sql query

Tags: sql, oracle

In `sql` i got a scenario like to add a `constant` value to one of the `condition data`  of `query` also the `constant data` that we going to add is coming from a `sub query`. The rough `sql` will be like this(As most of the sql datas are confidential I can't able to share the actual query).

```
SELECT * FROM test_table tt
  INNER JOIN test_table_1 tt1
    ON tt.id = tt1.id
  WHERE TO_DATE(tt1.CONDITION_VALUE, 'yyyy-mm-dd') >=
          TO_DATE('2011-08-25', 'yyyy-mm-dd') + (SELECT CONDITION_VALUE
                                                   FROM test_table tt
                                                   INNER JOIN test_table_1 tt1
                                                     ON tt.id = tt1.id
                                                   WHERE CONDITION_SEQUENCE='2') AND
        CONDITION_SEQUENCE='1'.
```

Issue is `subselect` will return a set of `data`. So I getting the error `ORA-01427: single-row subquery returns more than one row`.

Also, what is the `best` way to address this issue.

Simply: The scenario is, I want to calulate one `rows` values, based on the value from `another` row, but of the same parent object.

As far my understanding, now the `joins` were behaving like this

```
    obj1.data + [set of subquery data]
    obj2.data + [set of subquery data]
    ....
    objN.data + [set of subquery data]
```

Rather I want like

```
    obj1.data + obj1.anotherData
    obj2.data + obj2.anotherData
    ....
    objN.data + objN.anotherData
```

**Updated question**

Input is **purchase date** from: 2011-08-19 to: 2011-08-25, that i'll get from UI

Table value:

```
   id | CONDITION_SEQUENCE | CONDITION_VALUE |
   ------------------------|------------------
   1  | 1                  | 6               | --- purchase date
   2  | 1                  | 4               |
   3  | 2                  | 2011-08-25      | --- stay start date
   4  | 1                  | 2011-11-25      | --- stay end date
   --------------------------------------------
```

But in the purchase date, I having a value `6`, which I want to `add` or `subtract` from `stay start date`. Where all the `condition_value` belongs to one parent object, that i 'll determine by its parent table

Output: I want to calculate the `purchase date` as `2011-08-25`(stay start date) + `6`
(purchase date) =  `2011-08-19`

Comment: Where you want to add either in `where condition` or in `column`

Comment: @Exhausted In `where condition`

Comment: Please edit your question and provide sample data and desired results.  Your question shows a non-working query and doesn't explain what you are trying to do.

Comment: @Gordon Linoff Yes I understood. I updated my question

Comment: Which column you are adding with it. in where clause. because here i don't find any. Pattern looks like `WHERE CONDITION1 Expression value + (Subquery) and CONDITION2 expression vlue`. Here no logic with it

Comment: @Exhausted No,it will be like this `WHERE CONDITION1 Expression value + (Subquery)  CONDITION2 expression vlue`

Comment: Your update doesn't help.  You use columns and expressions that are not in your data.  Edit your question with **sample** data and **desired** results.

Comment: I don't where you are adding the subquery value to some column in `where condition`. I agree with @GordonLinoff point

Comment: @ Gordon Linoff updated the question

Comment: The subselect can't use `SELECT *...` when adding a value to a constant. You need to specify the column you want to add to the date constant. Best of luck.

Comment: @ Bob Jarvis, updated my question, as I gave a sample query, lot of confusion rised

Answer (score 1):

To accomplish what you seem to be trying to do you might try something like

```
SELECT *
  FROM test_table tt
  INNER JOIN test_table_1 tt1
    ON tt.id = tt1.id
  WHERE TO_DATE(tt1.CONDITION_VALUE, 'yyyy-mm-dd') >=
          TO_DATE('2011-08-25', 'yyyy-mm-dd') + tt.CONDITION_VALUE AND
        tt.CONDITION_SEQUENCE = '2' AND
        tt1.CONDITION_SEQUENCE = '1'
```

Best of luck.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your time, i got some idea from your answer accordingly i 'll try'

Comment: I couldn't able to test ur solution, mainly 'cause my issue is very difficult to explain and I just planned for java solutions, if you don't mind could u able to join the chat room

Comment: chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/592/mysql-and-relational-databases or chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/66379/oracle

Answer (score 1):

according to my understanding you can try like below,

```
SELECT tt.*,tt1.* FROM test_table tt
  INNER JOIN test_table_1 tt1
    ON tt.id = tt1.id
  INNER JOIN 
 test_table tt2
on tt.id = tt2.id 
  and tt2.CONDITION_SEQUENCE='2'
  WHERE TO_DATE(tt1.CONDITION_VALUE, 'yyyy-mm-dd') >=
          (TO_DATE('2011-08-25', 'yyyy-mm-dd') + tt2.CONDITION_VALUE) 
AND tt.CONDITION_SEQUENCE='1'
```

Comment: thanks for your answer let me try, also I'm trying to avoid extra `inner join` inside `sub query`

Comment: @Suganthan I think this might be efficent way rather than querying each and every time on `where` filter

Comment: let me check... I 'll get you with some time..in the db I having few other issue as well, that is blocking me

Comment: if you don't could you able to join the chat room http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/592/mysql-and-relational-databases or http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/66379/oracle